# Streamplot that masks a circular region

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm using streamplot in order to plot stress trajectories around an open circle. I do not want the stress trajectories to be analyzed inside the radius of the circle for two reasons: (1) The stresses will not propagate through the air as they would through the medium surrounding the hole, and (2) The math doesn't allow for it. I have been messing around with the idea of a mask but I haven't been able to get it to work. There might be a better way. Does anyone know how I can plot these trajectories without them plotting inside the radius of the hole? I effectively need some sort of command to tell the streamplot to stop whenever it gets to the outer radius of the hole, but then also know where to pick back up again. The first bit of code below is just the math used to derive the directions of the stress trajectories. I included this for reference. Following this I plot the trajectories.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *

def stress_trajectory_cartesian(X,Y,chi,F,a):
    # r is the radius out from the center of the hole at which we want to know the stress
    # Theta is the angle from reference at which we want to know the stress
    # a is the radius of the hole
    r = np.sqrt(np.power(X,2)+np.power(Y,2))*1.0
    c = (1.0*a)/(1.0*r)
    theta = np.arctan2(Y,X)

    A = 0.5*(1 - c**2. + (1 - 4*c**2. + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*theta))
    B = 0.5*(1 - c**2. - (1 - 4*c**2. + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*theta))
    C = 0.5*(1 + c**2. - (1 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*theta))
    D = 0.5*(1 + c**2. + (1+ 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*theta))
    E = 0.5*((1 + 2*c**2. - 3*c**4.)*np.sin(2*theta))

    tau_r = 1.0*F*c**2. + (A-1.0*chi*B) # Radial stress
    tau_theta = -1.*F*c**2. + (C - 1.0*chi*D) # Tangential stress
    tau_r_theta = (-1 - 1.0*chi)*E # Shear stress

    tau_xx = .5*tau_r*(np.cos(2*theta)+1) -1.0*tau_r_theta*np.sin(2*theta) + .5*(1-np.cos(2*theta))*tau_theta
    tau_xy = .5*np.sin(2*theta)*(tau_r - tau_theta) + 1.0*tau_r_theta*np.cos(2*theta)
    tau_yy = .5*(1-np.cos(2*theta))*tau_r + 1.0*tau_r_theta*np.sin(2*theta) + .5*(np.cos(2*theta)+1)*tau_theta

    tan_2B = (2.*tau_xy)/(1.0*tau_xx - 1.0*tau_yy)
    beta1 = .5*np.arctan(tan_2B)
    beta2 = .5*np.arctan(tan_2B) + np.pi/2.

    return beta1, beta2

# Functions to plot beta as a vector field in the Cartesian plane
def stress_beta1_cartesian(X,Y,chi,F,a):
    return stress_trajectory_cartesian(X,Y,chi,F,a)[0]
def stress_beta2_cartesian(X,Y,chi,F,a):
    return stress_trajectory_cartesian(X,Y,chi,F,a)[1]
#Used to return the directions of the betas
def to_unit_vector_x(angle):
    return np.cos(angle)
def to_unit_vector_y(angle):
    return np.sin(angle)
```

The code below plots the stress trajectories:

```
# Note that R_min is taken as the radius of the hole here
# Using R_min for a in these functions under the assumption that we don't want to analyze stresses across the hole

def plot_stresses_cartesian(F,chi,R_min):
    Y_grid, X_grid = np.mgrid[-5:5:100j, -5:5:100j]
    R_grid = np.sqrt(X_grid**2. + Y_grid**2.)

    cart_betas1 = stress_beta1_cartesian(X_grid,Y_grid,chi,F,R_min)
    beta_X1s = to_unit_vector_x(cart_betas1)
    beta_Y1s = to_unit_vector_y(cart_betas1)
    beta_X1s[R_grid<1] = np.nan
    beta_Y1s[R_grid<1] = np.nan

    cart_betas2 = stress_beta2_cartesian(X_grid,Y_grid,chi,F,R_min)
    beta_X2s = to_unit_vector_x(cart_betas2)
    beta_Y2s = to_unit_vector_y(cart_betas2)
    beta_X2s[R_grid<1] = np.nan
    beta_Y2s[R_grid<1] = np.nan

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))

    #streamplot
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_title('Stress Trajectories')
    plt.streamplot(X_grid, Y_grid, beta_X1s, beta_Y1s, minlength=0.9, arrowstyle='-', density=2.5, color='b')
    plt.streamplot(X_grid, Y_grid, beta_X2s, beta_Y2s, minlength=0.9, arrowstyle='-', density=2.5, color='r')
    plt.axis("image")
    plt.xlabel(r'$\chi = $'+str(round(chi,1)) + ', ' + r'$F = $'+ str(round(F,1)))
    plt.ylim(-5,5)
    plt.xlim(-5,5)

    plt.show()

plot_stresses_cartesian(0,1,1)
```

Comment: Would it suffice to paste a white (opaque) circle on top of the streamplot?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I was doing this at first and so I didn't realize what was messing up. When r goes to zero, I am dividing by zero in numerous places in the math (note: c = a/r appears several times). This is causing errors in the plotting near the hole, which is the most important place to examine @unutbu

Comment: What is the desired (correct value) that `stress_trajectory_cartesian` should return as `r` goes to zero? or should I say `r < a`?

Comment: I do not want to analyze r < a because it is divergent. How can I tell my code to stop once it gets to r == a , without causing problems with the trajectories? One idea I had was to utilize the fact that the trajectories will be symmetrical about the hole. So for beta1, they are symmetrical about the y-axis and beta2 is symmetrical about the x-axis. This means I could  just plot one side of the hole, until r = a, and then display that same plot on the other side also. What do you think? @unutbu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just need to have `NaN` values for the region that you do not want to consider. I generated a simple example below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Y, X = np.mgrid[-5:5:100j, -5:5:100j]
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
U = -1 - X**2 + Y
V = 1 + X - Y**2
U[R<1] = np.nan
V[R<1] = np.nan

plt.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, density=2.5, arrowstyle='-')
plt.axis("image")
plt.savefig("stream.png", dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

With plot

[image]

Comment: This seems to be the right idea for sure! For some reason, when I adapted this bit of code to fit my problem, I didn't get the desired effect. Instead of only applying nan values to the region inside the radius < 1, mine is assigning nans to the intervals between -1 and 1. I do not understand nor can I figure out why it is doing this. I've introduced my updated code above @nicoguaro

Comment: @Ned, if you change (or remove) the ``minlength`` then you might get something closer to my image.